# VisualStyleRenderer.GetPartSize for window caption buttons returns wrong value

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

For specific reason I need to know the exact width of each caption bar button of a Winforms Form: Maximize, Minimize and a Close button.

The code has to work correct on versions of Windows that are higher or equal to Windows XP SP3.

I try to do it in a following way in my Form class:

```
    var graphics = CreateGraphics();
    var renderer = new VisualStyleRenderer(VisualStyleElement.Window.CloseButton.Normal);
    Size closeButtonWidth = renderer.GetPartSize(graphics, ThemeSizeType.True);
```

I call this code in my Form's `OnSizeChanged` override.
Trying this code on my Windows 8 OS, I figured out that the return value is very wrong: the return size is: {Width=28, Height=17}.
And the actual size that I can see on the screen on my monitor is the next: {Width=45, Height=19} (can't post image, as I don't have enough reputation yet).

For another Form caption buttons, like Minimize or Maximize, `VisualStyleRenderer.GetPartSize` also returns wrong values: {Width=5, Height=17}.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: See Remarks from [VisualStyleRenderer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstylerenderer(v=vs.110).aspx): **Windows XP Home Edition, Windows XP Professional x64 Edition, Windows Server 2003 Platform Note:** Visual styles are supported only on these platforms.

Comment: This is a known problem on Windows 8.x with no known workaround.  The core issue is that the visual styles renderer categorically refuses to reproduce the Windows 8.x frame style, it will only render the Aero look.  You therefore get Aero metrics.  If there's any solution to this then it is a very well-kept secret.  If it is important then open a support case with Microsoft Support.  Don't expect a miracle though.

Comment: Nothing to do? Not even any WinApi function? Any suggestion then? Maybe hardcore some constants? But with changing window caption font size in Windows, the caption buttons will change size too.